# How to create 'Black box' in FastAPI docs response model

Tags: python, fastapi, swagger-ui

In the docs [link](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/?h=response%20docs#see-it-in-the-docs) I saw that for description you can have 'Black box' surrounding the description of the response code:
[image: Next to code 200]
That 'Black box' where 'Successful Response' is written, how to achieve that?

Comment: This "black box" was actually a [bug](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4173) in older Swagger UI versions where it rendered response descriptions as code blocks instead of as Markdown text. It's been fixed since then (I don't recall in which version). If you prefer the old appearance, you can try to emulate it by tweaking Swagger UI's CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a [bug](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4173), so can't be done anymore